# Building a post liking feature on React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Im trying to build a post(task/comments) liking feature for a project management website.
My current logic is, using the user id, task id, and a boolean taskLiked variable that stores if a task is liked or not.

So far this is what I have

```
this.state = {

taskLikeInfo: [],
 //an array containing taskId, userId, taskLiked boolean for each user who likes/unlikes a post
}
```

event handler for like button

```
handleClick(event) {

        var tasks = this.state.taskLikeInfo;
        const result = tasks.filter(task => ((task.taskId==this.props.activeTask)&&(task.userId==this.props.user.id)));
        console.log('tasks,result:', tasks, result)
        if (result.taskLiked===true)
        {
            this.unlikeTask(event)

        }
        else  {
            this.likeTask(event)

        }
    }
```

the like function

```
likeTask(){

  var taskId = this.props.activeTask;
  var userId = this.props.user.id;
  var tasks = this.state.taskLikeInfo;
  tasks.push({ taskId, userId, taskLiked:true })
  var destArray = _.uniq(tasks, function(x){
    return x.taskId;
  });
  this.setState({taskLikeInfo : tasks})
}
```

the unlike function

```
unlikeTask(){

  var taskId = this.props.activeTask;
  var userId = this.props.user.id;
  var tasks = this.state.taskLikeInfo;
  this.props.unlikeTask(taskId,userId)
  // _.uniq takes a json array and eliminates all repeating elements so that the final array can be used to count total unique likes on a post
  var destArray = _.uniq(tasks, function(x){
    return x.taskLiked;
  });
  destArray.map((task, index) => {
    if((task.taskId==taskId)&& (task.userId==userId) && (task.taskLiked===true)){
      //the user is clicking on an already liked comment which should toggle it
      task.taskLiked=false;

    }
  })

  this.setState({taskLikeInfo: destArray})
}
```

the render() function

```
<div className="like-task">
  <a class="btn btn-sm" onClick={this.handleClick} data-taskid={this.props.activeTask} >    
    { this.state.taskLikeInfo.map((task, index) => {
      return (
        <i className={"fa fa-" + ( task.taskLiked ? 'heart-o' : 'heart')} > </i>
      );
    }) }  
    Like
  </a>
</div>
```

1. if the same comment is being liked/unliked it is working
2. if comment A is liked then comment B is liked, then comment A is unliked first and then comment B is liked (in the same click)

Can someone please fix my current code or suggest a different more cleaner work around. Thankyou.
codepen demo..
https://codepen.io/rafay-shahid/pen/dKwagV?editors=1011

Comment: Are you keeping same state for all tasks?

Comment: Yes all tasks data are in the same state in taskLikeInfo[]

Comment: you must have an array of the task and like flag for all those task. Currently signle flag is used. So it will updated latest flag value to all

Comment: I edited the post with the logic you have suggested and it does make more sense now. But still the tasks.filter() function does not return any matched objects in handleClick and the so the unlike function is not being called

Comment: can you create a codepen or plunkr for it ?
will be easy to debug there

Comment: I have given it test inputs. for any task clicked it should toggle the taskLiked variable for that particular task. and store it in the state:taskLikeInfo... here
https://codepen.io/rafay-shahid/pen/dKwagV?editors=0111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refactor this to make the logic more simple, as well as fix the issue you specifically described.

When you render your like buttons - you want to pass the taskID along with the handleClick.

```
onClick={this.handleClick(this.props.activeTask)}
```

Inside of your onClickHandler:

```
handleClick(event, taskId) {
  //if task is currently liked by user
  //unlike it
  //else like it
  //update state with new likes
}
```

I would write the code, but without an example of the data structure it's difficult.

Comment: Passing the activeTask id in handleClick helped me render liked states individually based on its state. Thankyou, this works!